Integral representation of Lambert Series.
Is there a general integral representation for Lambert series, similar to those that exist for various L-series and zeta functions?
For a sequence of complex numbers $\{a_n\}$, its corresponding Lambert series is defined as the infinite series of the form:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n q^n}{1 - q^n}
$$
Many important L-series and zeta functions have integral representations that converge for certain complex values of their parameters. For example:

The Riemann zeta function:
$$
\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x - 1} \, dx \quad (\text{for } \Re(s) > 1)
$$

The polylogarithm:
$$
\text{Li}_s(z) = \frac{z}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t - z} \, dt \quad (\text{for } |z| < 1 \text{ and } \Re(s) > 0)
$$

The Hurwitz zeta function:
$$
\zeta(s,a) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1} e^{-at}}{1 - e^{-t}} \, dt \quad (\text{for } \Re(s) > 1 \text{ and } \Re(a) > 0)
$$


My question is: Does there exist a general integral representation for Lambert series, similar to these examples? If not for all Lambert series, are there any known integral representations for specific subclasses of Lambert series?

An interesting question, I look forward to what you learn.

There isn't a general one for Dirichlet series.
